# RadComboBox Binding displaying type instead of desired string

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, styles

I have a radcombobox with two templates, one template(the nonEditableTemplate) works fine and displays the string I want, the other just displays the type instead. Both of the comboboxes display the correct values when the drop down is open, but the editable comboboxes selectionbox(display) is incorrect and displaying (Assembly).(Class). I've looked through stack overflow and google and have found quite a few examples using DisplayMemberPath and such, but nothing with a converter.

xaml in the user control

```
<telerik:RadComboBox
        Width="200"
        Height="50"
        IsEditable="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding People, Mode=TwoWay, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Style="{DynamicResource GcsComboBox}">
        <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PersonToNameConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Global Style for combobox

```
<Style x:Key="GcsComboBox" TargetType="telerik:RadComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,3" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="22" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource LabelBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NonEditableComboBox}" />
        <Setter Property="EditableTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditableComboBox}" />
        <Setter Property="NonEditableTemplate" Value="{StaticResource NonEditableComboBox}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <!--<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ValidationTooltipTemplate}" />-->
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Continue" />
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="telerik:RadComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="telerik:RadComboBoxItem">
                                <Border
                                    x:Name="Bd"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                    <ContentPresenter
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource HoverGradient}" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource HoverGradient}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Global style for editable combobox

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="EditableComboBox" TargetType="telerik:RadComboBox">
        <Grid x:Name="VisualRoot">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
                x:Name="Background"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"
                CornerRadius="3"
                IsHitTestVisible="False" />
            <Border
                x:Name="Border"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                CornerRadius="3"
                IsHitTestVisible="False" />
            <Border
                x:Name="MouseOverVisual"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Background="{DynamicResource SelectedGradient}"
                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource HoverGradient}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                CornerRadius="3"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Opacity="0" />
            <Border
                x:Name="DropDownOpenBorder"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                CornerRadius="3"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <TextBox
                x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="1,1,0,1"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding 
HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"
                Foreground="{DynamicResource InputTextBrush}"
                IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}">
                <TextBox.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <ScrollViewer
                                x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding 
BorderThickness}"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </TextBox.Template>
            </TextBox>
            <telerik:RadToggleButton
                x:Name="PART_DropDownButton"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"
                ClickMode="Press"
                IsTabStop="False"
                Style="{StaticResource NonEditableComboToggleButtonStyle}" 
/>
            <Border
                x:Name="Focus"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                CornerRadius="3"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="Watermark"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Opacity=".5"
                Text="{TemplateBinding EmptyText}"
                Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup">
                <Border
                    x:Name="PART_ResizeBorder"
                    MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinDropDownWidth}"
                    MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                    Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"
                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <telerik:RadButton
                            x:Name="PART_ClearButton"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding 
ClearSelectionButtonContent}"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding 
ClearSelectionButtonVisibility}" />
                        <ScrollViewer
                            x:Name="PART_ScrollViewer"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Padding="1"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            CanContentScroll="True"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownOpenBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownOpenBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{DynamicResource BorderBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                To="0.3"
                                Duration="0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverVisual"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                To="1"
                                Duration="0:0:0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="DropDownOpen">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Focus"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                To="0"
                                Duration="0" />
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{DynamicResource BorderBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownOpenBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Focus" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WatermarkStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="WatermarkVisible">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Watermark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="WatermarkInvisible" />
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Here is the NonEditableTemplate that is giving the desired affect.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="NonEditableComboBox" TargetType="telerik:RadComboBox">
        <Grid x:Name="VisualRoot">
            <Border
                x:Name="Background"
                Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"
                CornerRadius="3"
                IsHitTestVisible="False" />
            <telerik:RadToggleButton
                x:Name="PART_DropDownButton"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                ClickMode="Press"
                Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                IsTabStop="False"
                Style="{DynamicResource NonEditableComboToggleButtonStyle}" 
/>
            <Border
                x:Name="Focus"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                CornerRadius="3"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup">
                <Border
                    x:Name="PART_ResizeBorder"
                    MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinDropDownWidth}"
                    MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                    Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"
                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <telerik:RadButton
                            x:Name="PART_ClearButton"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding 
ClearSelectionButtonContent}"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding 
ClearSelectionButtonVisibility}" />
                        <ScrollViewer
                            x:Name="PART_ScrollViewer"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Padding="1"
                            Background="{DynamicResource 
ControlBackgroundBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            CanContentScroll="True"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding 
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="DropDownOpen">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Focus"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="
(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                To="0"
                                Duration="0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
Storyboard.TargetName="Focus" Storyboard.TargetProperty="
(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Use `DisplayMemberPath` property

Comment: How so? I'm returning a string from a converter. Sometimes with multiple properties concatenated. If I were simply binding to one property of my viewmodel then I can see using that. But not when using a converter.

Comment: @Marsh It appears that `PersonToNameConverter` isn't returning what you think it is. By the way, `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` are no-ops on your `ItemsSource` Binding. They can't possibly have any effect.

Comment: Ahh thank you for that info. However, If I set the combobox to use the noneditable template, using the same converter, I do get the desired result

Comment: What does the binding look like in that case? Is it the exact same binding? In any case, the TextBox is showing whatever the converter gives it. Put a breakpoint in the converter and see what that is.

Comment: By "the noneditable template", do you mean letting it use its default template? Actually can you just provide the complete XAML for the version that shows you want you want?

Comment: Ahh ok, so it is the same binding, but after stepping through more carefully it doesn't get into the converter after I select an option when it's the editable template.

Comment: I added the non editable template that gives the correct output. I'm guessing now that it has something to do with the fact that it's a textbox

Comment: The TextBlock idea doesn't sound right to me at all. But so the converter gets invoked in the "non-editable" template, but not in the "editable" template. Have you confirmed that the `ItemTemplate` `DataTemplate` is actually being used when you use the "editable" template? I'd give the DataTemplate TextBlock a Red background or something so you can be sure that's getting used. I'd also add `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to that binding in the DataTemplate, and see what turns up in the Output pane in VS at runtime.

Comment: The converter is getting hit when i open the drop down 3 times(i have 3 items in my list). Then when I select one it should get hit again. On the "nonEditable" it does get hit. On the "editable" it does not get hit. I did change the bg color and in the "nonEditable" the value displays red in the list, and after I've selected it will remain red in the Display area/SelectionBox. The "editable" will be red in the drop down, but once it's selected will no longer be red in the display.

Comment: When changing values with the "nonEditable" template I get output that shows that the value is changing. With the "editable" there is no output when selecting between different values. Only when initially opening the dropdown

Comment: Ahhh, it's not using that template to display the selected item. And no wonder: You can't edit the text in a TextBlock. Does RadComboBox have a property like `ItemEditTemplate` or something?

Answer (score 0):

[Quoth Telerik](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcombobox/features/populating-with-data-selectionbox):

> ...if you want to customize the TextBox part of Editable RadComboBox you could use the [TextBoxStyle](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcombobox/features/textboxstyle) property.

Here's their example

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="CustomComboTextBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
    <!-- blah blah blah -->
</Style>
```

I would suggest writing a `Style` for the `TextBoxStyle` property which sets `Text` to your `Binding` with `PersonToNameConverter`.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="CustomComboTextBoxStyle">
    <Setter 
        Property="Text" 
        Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PersonToNameConverter}}" 
        />
</Style>
```

And since you're customizing the entire template of the `RadComboBox`, I would also take care to ensure that your version is not interfering with the usage of `TextBoxStyle`.

Comment: Did you happen to try this and get it working. I'm unable to get it working. I've created the resource and key and set TextBoxStyle to my key resource and it throws an exc. "Failed to initialize RadComboBox"

Comment: Also with this solution i'd have to go through to every comboBox and add somthing of this sort. I feel like there has to be an easier way to just set it in the global styles

Comment: Once you get the TextBoxStyle working you would set it in the global style for RadComboBox. I don't have the Telerik controls. Does it work with an empty Style with the correct TargetType?

Comment: yeah even at it's most basic/minimum it breaks.

Comment: Does it work with the standard RadComboBox template?

Comment: No it didn't, I took all of my custom styles and templates off and assigned that resource to the textbox style and it broke.